# Convert a sentence to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

How can I convert a sentence to an array?

I have this code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter your sentence: ");
String sentence = scanner.next();

String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

But... all this does is just print out the first word of the array and thats it.

Answer (score 1):

`next` is only literally consuming the next String.  Use `nextLine` instead.

```
String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
```

The reason:  [`nextLine()` advances the scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) past the newline, which means that it captures the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner.next()
```

reads only the next token - not the next line. You want: [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

I've added a debugging statement that should make clear a pretty big problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SentenceToWords {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter your sentence: ");
      String sentence = scanner.next();

      //USEFUL INFORMATION!!!
      System.out.println("sentence=\"" + sentence + "\"");

      String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

      for (String word : words) {
          System.out.println(word);
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java SentenceToWords
Enter your sentence: setao uhesno uhoesuthesao uh
sentence="setao"
setao
```

As stated by @Makoto: You're only reading in a word, when you want to read in a line.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you are using Scanner, which ignores a string after a space, if you use `next()`. Use `nextLine()` instead.

Comment: is my code is wrong ? please edit it, beside down vote.... its not a competition so u are -1 ...